# Using nodejs bindings to run native c++ code produces an error

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to develop an electron app, and I would like to use an npm package that gives vibrancy to a window. This is the package I'm trying to use: https://github.com/sebascontre/windows10-fluently-vibrancy

It uses a visual c++ code to call native windows methods to achieve this vibrancy effect.

I've cloned and I've run the `npm install` and build as described in the readme and ran the following:

```
npm install
npm run conf
npm run rebuild
```

All built successfully and I also see the `build\debug` artifacts of the c++ build.

When I try to run it (as described in readme):

```
cd spec\app
electron .
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\F:\Development\windows10-fluently-vibrancy\build\Debug\Vibrancy.node
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar.js:155:31)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:857:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar.js:155:31)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:609:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:601:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:715:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at bindings (F:\Development\windows10-fluently-vibrancy\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:112:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Development\windows10-fluently-vibrancy\index.js:1:35)
```

[image]

According to the message it cannot find the `Vibrancy.node` file - But I've verified that it exists in the specified location.

Any ideas how to make it run? I have cloned the package to test it since when trying to use the npm itself in my project it gave the same error so I figured I would try the source.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the exact same issue you're describing here.

I got it to work using [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild).
From the root of your project run the command: `electron-rebuild`

Hope this helps you, if not, maybe someone else.